# MemoryTributary GetBuffer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, out-of-memory

My application is MVC5 C#, I use memorystream to generate images using the following:

```
                  using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        const int quality = 90; 
                        var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)quality);
                        objImage.Save(memStream, GetImageCodeInfo("image/png"), encoderParameters);
                       data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
                        memStream.Dispose();

                      }
```

However I get OutOfMemoryException with some files.  I was reading about MemoryTributary but could not find a solution to GetBuffer!  Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about leaving all the buffer stuff out?

```
var memStream = new MemoryStream();

const int quality = 90; 
var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)quality);
objImage.Save(memStream, GetImageCodeInfo("image/png"), encoderParameters);

memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return File(memStream, "image/png");
```

The FileStreamResult will dispose the MemoryStream, no need to worry about that.